# Tin Can Statements

Tags: tin-can-api

I am a newbie of Tincan so can anyone guide me on this query?

I am creating a tincan statement Plugin for my wordpress website.
I took help from http://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCanPHP/ to understand how to send the statements to the LRS and the statements is going perfectly to the LRS. Now i want to create each Activity of the user on the site, like if a user logged in then the statement $user is looged in now must be created, if the user completed a Course the statement $user completed the Course must be generated but through http://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCanPHP/ example only one type of statement is created

Now if i want e-mail@domain.com is loggedin now then using the code of Rusticisoftware how can i create multiple actors , Verb and Activity. Please provide me the code snippet for this issue if possible.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple statements using the TinCanPHP library, you can either use the saveStatement method mentioned in the documentation you linked multiple times (once for each event you want to track) or if you have multiple statements being sent at the same time you can use saveStatements and pass an array of statement objects.

Does this answer your question? If not, what exactly are you trying to do and where are you getting stuck. Do you have a design for your plugin covering which statements you want to send and what data you want to track in each one? You may find [this blog](http://tincanapi.com/blog/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=blog?pmc=em-1) helpful.